# Change mysql_ functions with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to rewrite my php code with mysql_* functions with PDO so I have:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'gmaestro_agro', 'pass') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysql_select_db('gmaestro_agro', $con); 

    mysql_select_db('gmaestro_agro', $con);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `stat` (`Name`, `Gender`, `Age`, `Donuts eaten`) VALUES (";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']) . "', ";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Gender']) . "', ";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Age']) . "', ";
      $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Donuts_eaten']);
      $query .= "')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result != false) {
        echo "success!";
    } else {
        echo "an error occured saving your data!";
    }

?>
```

and I try to write this but with PDO function like this:

```
<?php


    /* Your Database Name */
    $dbname = 'gmaestro_agro';

    /* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
    $username = 'gmaestro_agro';
    $password = 'pass';

     $stmt = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO stat(Name,
            Gender,
            Age,
            Donuts eaten
            ) VALUES (
            :Name, 
            :Gender, 
            :Age, 
            :Donuts_eaten)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':Name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':Gender', $_POST['gender'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':Age', $_POST['age'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
// use PARAM_STR although a number  
$stmt->bindParam(':Donuts_eaten', $_POST['Donuts_eaten'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

$stmt->execute(); 
if($stmt != false) {
        echo "success!";
    } else {
        echo "an error occured saving your data!";
    }

    ?>
```

I dont get any error just nothing happend? Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: You need to wrap `Donuts eaten` in backticks (your column name), due to the space. Unless that's a typo, change to `Donuts_eaten`

Comment: Donuts eaten column name is the prime suspect in this investigation

Comment: No my column in mysql database is donuts eaten

Comment: then my comment applies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit (successful test code)

Table and data creation codes used for the successful insertion (test).

Column `Donuts_eaten` has been used with an underscore instead of a space.

You can base yourself on this:

**Table creation codes** in PHPmyadmin

**Note:** Change `your_db_name` to your Database name.

```
CREATE TABLE `your_db_name`.`stat` (
`Name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`Gender` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`Age` INT NOT NULL ,
`Donuts_eaten` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

**HTML form**

**Note:** `<input type="text" name="Donuts_eaten">` - `Donuts_eaten` is not the same as `donuts_eaten` notice the lowercase `d`

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: 
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
Gender: 
<input type="text" name="gender">
<br>
Age: 
<input type="text" name="age">
<br>
Donuts eaten: 
<input type="text" name="Donuts_eaten">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP/SQL**

```
<?php
/* Your Database Name */
$dbname = 'dbname'; // change this

/* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
$username = 'username'; // change this
$password = 'password'; // change this

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO stat (Name,
        Gender,
        Age,
        Donuts_eaten
        ) VALUES (
        :Name, 
        :Gender, 
        :Age, 
        :Donuts_eaten)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':Name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':Gender', $_POST['gender'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':Age', $_POST['age'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
// use PARAM_STR although a number  
$stmt->bindParam(':Donuts_eaten', $_POST['Donuts_eaten'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

// old execute
// $stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->execute(array(':Name' => $_POST['name'],':Gender' => $_POST['gender'],':Age' => $_POST['age'],':Donuts_eaten' => $_POST['Donuts_eaten']));
if($stmt != false) {
    echo "success!";
} else {
    echo "an error occured saving your data!";
}

?>
```

---

### Original answer

You need to wrap `Donuts eaten` in backticks (for your column name), due to the space.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stat(Name,
        Gender,
        Age,
        `Donuts eaten`
        ) VALUES (
        :Name, 
        :Gender, 
        :Age, 
        :Donuts_eaten)";
```

Using spaces in column names is discouraged. Use an underscore instead for your table's column.

Also, change:

```
$stmt = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

to:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

because you're using `$pdo` in `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);`

Comment: Now I get error: home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php on line 34

Comment: yes I know that I change it but again : home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php on line 34

Comment: try here: http://agrotime.roadvoyage.com/index3.html click on add new button and submit form ...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up your variables, `$pdo` is undefined / not your database connection.

You can probably solve it by using:

```
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

instead of:

```
 $stmt = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And if a table or column name contains spaces, you need to quote them in backticks:

```
        Gender,
        Age,
        `Donuts eaten`
        ) VALUES (
```

But with the first change, PDO should throw an exception to show you this problem.

Comment: I get this error: manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'eaten ) VALUES ( NULL, NULL, N' at line 4' in /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home1/gmaestro/public_html/agrotime/insert.php on line 34

Comment: @user3285234 See the comments below your question and the last part of my answer.